# Django ManyToMany query with listening in template

Tags: django, django-templates, many-to-many

I'm struggling with ManytoMany relationship. What i'm trying to do is to get all applications with their coresponding servers ( an application can exist on more then one server ) and list them in template. So far I know how to query for Server using 'prefetch_related' and print them in template but how to query all Applicaions with their corresponding Servers and print them in template ?

Example template:

```
'Some www application','www server','database server for www server'...
```

Thank you in advance.

```
class Server(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=40,unique=True)

class Application(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    book = models.ManyToManyField(Server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `prefetch_related` on a query for `Application`s:

```
def some_view(request):
    applications = Application.objects.prefetch_related('book')
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', {'applications': applications})
```

In the template you can then render this with:

```
{% for application in applications %}
    <b>application.name</b> {% for server in application.book.all %}{{ server.title }}{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Dunno why but still can't get list of servers related to application. Shouldn't there be something similar to "q=Application.objects.all().prefetch_related('book_set')"  and then in template "{% for app in application.book_set.all %}"    - i'm not sure but querying in other way works for me well as well as in template ?

Comment: @admfotad, no since you named the relation `book = ...`, but perhaps you obfucated too much?

Comment: my class is a bit bigger and i wanted to show it in much easier way - that's why books shows up  :P